# How does Wordpress handle all URL formats without .htaccess changes?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Wordpress gives you the option to change your permalink structure to basically anything you want. While I am aware of how to do this by editing the `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` files, I don't understand how Wordpress does it.

How can I funnel all URLs through a single PHP file without changing the .htaccess or server configuration?

Comment: It doesn't, it actually changes the `.HTACCESS` file on server. To elaborate, if WordPress has write permissions to the file then it only edits the rules within the WordPress area, which is wrapped by comments. So any rules you already have are carried over.

Comment: What if Wordpress doesn't have write permissions? Or AllowOverride is turned off? Will the installation fail?

Comment: @hellohellosharp No, it'll just default to non-pretty permalinks. You can then edit the `.htaccess` manually (WordPress will provide the rules in the interface, even).

Comment: @ceejayoz - Thanks, accepted your answer. I'm assuming a non-pretty link looks something like this: `http://example.com/index.php?id=blah` ?

Comment: @hellohellosharp Pretty much - `http://example.com/?p=###` where `###` is the post ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WordPress `.htaccess`, once in place, requires no changes for new URLs. It reroutes any request for a URL that isn't an existing file or directory to `index.php`, which then takes the URL and looks into the database for what to display.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This is known as a [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and is commonly used in modern web development frameworks.

Comment: "The WordPress .htaccess" - this is what I can't find. I don't see a .htaccess file in the wordpress ZIP.

Comment: @hellohellosharp The default contents are listed at https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess for you. I believe it'll offer to create it if necessary, but I feel the webserver being able to edit `.htaccess` (as well as the `.php` files) is a significant security issue and prevent it.